# How to change formatting of Line chart axis

Tags: python, formatting, seaborn, axis

I'm doing a time series analysis using the following code using seaborn in python,

```
df['Crop'] = pd.Categorical(df['Crop'], categories=df['Crop'].dropna().unique())
pd.to_datetime(df['DisplayDate'], format='%y-%m-%d')
cols = df['Gr']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(cols), figsize=(6,3))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x= df['DisplayDate'], y= df['Crop'], hue= df['Gr'])
plt.show()
```

the graph comes out with scribbles in the x-axis like this:

[image]

My thought is that i might be due to the size of the dates. Is there a way to change the formatting of the x-axis so that instead of showing the entire date, it only shows the month?

Comment: Did you try `df['DisplayDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DisplayDate'], format='%y-%m-%d')` to save the column into a suitable format?

Comment: yes, that column si read as a string object and i used that line to convert it to a datetime object

Comment: the scribbles still show

Comment: You need to use Johan's full code. Your current code is incomplete because it does not save back to `df['DisplayDate']`, so the column is still `object` type.